# Returning multiple minimax values [score, x, y] using structs in C

Tags: c++, c, struct, minimax, game-theory

The issue in my code lies in the minimax algorithm, more specifically the return values. My current solution written in C++ is below, using tuples, returning score, x and y positions.
I've decided to do something similar in C using struct.

The algorithm finds every possible endstate given the current board position [3468] correctly, but doesn't return correct next move coordinates.

Given that it is X-s turn, we should get [score = 0, x = 0, y = 1] from the function. Currently the returned values are [score = 1, x = 1, y = 0].

How should I implement the struct correctly for the algorithm to work properly?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int s = 3; //Board size
int cnt = 0;
char player = 'X', opponent = 'O';

struct Best {
  int score, x, y;
};

void printBoard(char v[][s]);
char eval(char v[][s]);
struct Best miniMax(char Table[][s], int depth, bool isMaximising); //Problem: structs?

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char b[3][3] = {
    {'X','_','_'},
    {'_','O','_'},
    {'_','_','_'}
  };
  printBoard(b);

  struct Best s = miniMax(b, 0, true);
  printf("Possible games: %d\n", cnt);
  cnt = 0;
  printf("Score: %d, Best move: [%d][%d]\n", s.score, s.x, s.y);

  return 0;
}
void printBoard(char v[][s]){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++){
    for (size_t j = 0; j < s; j++){
      printf("%c|", v[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
char eval(char v[][s]){
  for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    if (v[i][0] == v[i][1] && v[i][1] == v[i][2] && v[i][0] != '_') //Row
    return v[i][0];
    if (v[0][i] == v[1][i] && v[1][i] == v[2][i] && v[0][i] != '_') //Col
    return v[0][i];
  }
  if (v[0][0] == v[1][1] && v[1][1] == v[2][2] && v[0][0] != '_') //Diag
  return v[0][0];

  if (v[0][2] == v[1][1] && v[1][1] == v[2][0] && v[0][2] != '_') //Diag2
  return v[0][2];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < s; j++) {
      if (v[i][j] == '_')
      return '\0';
    }
  }
  return '=';
}
```

Here is the problematic miniMax function implementation in C:

```
struct Best miniMax(char Table[][s], int depth, bool isMaximising) {
  struct Best v;
  char result = eval(Table);
  if (result == 'X') {
    cnt++;
    v.score = 1;
    v.x = 0;
    v.y = 0;
    return v;
  }
  if (result == 'O') {
    cnt++;
    v.score = -1;
    v.x = 0;
    v.y = 0;
    return v;
  }
  if (result == '=') {
    cnt++;
    v.score = 0;
    v.x = 0;
    v.y = 0;
    return v;
  }
  if (isMaximising) {
    int bestScore = -100;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < s; j++) {
        if (Table[i][j] == '_') {
          Table[i][j] = player;
          v = miniMax(Table, depth + 1, false);
          if (v.score > bestScore) {
            bestScore = v.score;
            v.score = bestScore;
            v.x = i;
            v.y = j;
          }
          Table[i][j] = '_';
        }
      }
    }
    return v;
  } else {
    int bestScore = 100;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < s; j++) {
        if (Table[i][j] == '_') {
          Table[i][j] = opponent;
          v = miniMax(Table, depth + 1, true);
          if (v.score < bestScore) {
            bestScore = v.score;
            v.score = bestScore;
            v.x = i;
            v.y = j;
          }
          Table[i][j] = '_';
        }
      }
    }
    return v;
  }
}
```

Implementation in C++:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

tuple <int, int, int> Minimax(char Board[][s], int depth, bool isMaximising){
  char res = eval(Board);

  if (res == 'X') {
    cnt++;
    return {1, 0, 0};
  }
  if (res == 'O') {
    cnt++;
    return {-1, 0, 0};
  }
  if (res == '=') {
    cnt++;
    return {0, 0, 0};
  }

  if (isMaximising) {
    int bestScore = -100;
    int px = 0, py = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < s; j++) {
        if (Board[i][j] == '_') {
          Board[i][j] = player;
          auto [score, x, y] = Minimax(Board, depth + 1, false);
          if (score > bestScore) {
            bestScore = score;
            px = i;
            py = j;
          }
          Board[i][j] = '_';
        }
      }
    }
    return {bestScore, px, py};
  } else {
    int bestScore = 100;
    int qx = 0, qy = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      for (size_t j = 0; j < s; j++) {
        if (Board[i][j] == '_') {
          Board[i][j] = opponent;
          auto [score, x, y] = Minimax(Board, depth + 1, true);
          if (score < bestScore) {
            bestScore = score;
            qx = i;
            qy = j;
          }
          Board[i][j] = '_';
        }
      }
    }
    return {bestScore, qx, qy};
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the question and where is an issue? Show the desired input/output.

Comment: @yvw How to obtain correct values from function minimax using struct? Input is board state as char array, output has to be [score = 0, x = 0, y = 1], because it is the best and correct move, but is [score = 1, x = 1, y = 0]

Comment: This link https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/545705 has some insights to where you should post if you have a specific problem. If your issue is with the `C` code, then show us what have you tried. Maybe run it with a debugger and compare with C++ version?

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem is that every time miniMax recursively calls itself, it overwrites `v` with the returned value, losing the saved best value from any earlier iteration.  So you always end up with x/y from the last tested position, not from the best found one.

Add a new `struct Best best` value that is the one you update and return when you find a better move.  Note that you also don't need the `bestScore` local then -- you can just use `best.score`

Comment: Could you be more specific in visual terms? where exactly should the changes be made in the code?

Comment: In miniMax, everywhere you have `v.whatever =` change it to `best.whatever =` and change all the returns to `return best;`.  Other uses of `v` don't change.  You can also change `bestScore` to `best.score` everywhere,